# tableSvc.retrieveEntity retrieves previous version of Azure Table Storage data

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-table-storage, azure-bot-service

I have a waterfall of dialogs in Bot Framework SDK3,
each dialog does something, until it switches to dialog with tableSvc.retrieveEntity which correctly identifies a required to be retrieved entity (according to given PartionKey & RowKey) from Azure Table...

...but the entity which is retreived (I check it with console.log('Result') is outdated (one step [a few seconds, which pass during conversation of user with a bot] behind the actual data stored in Azure Tables - the real data which needs to be retrieved in this dialog...)

The Conversation is not closed yet (it will be later) - it is important to store and retrieve actual data at this stage...

How to get actual data in this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for those of you who had similar problem...
I guess, it has to do with event loop of Node.js...

I'm not sure whether it is a bullet-proof solution, or a temporary 'hack', 
but I put it like this and it works (when I try to use setTimeout 0 ms - it does not work for me, when I set it to 500ms - it works, so I guess 1000 ms could be a safe temporary hack..before I find better solution)..

If someone knows a better, more robust, solution, please, update this thread.

```
setTimeout( () => {
      tableSvc.retrieveEntity('table', pkey, rkey, funcdtion(error, result, response) {
        if(!error) {
          var res1 = result.Data._;
          console.log(res1); // Now it prints actual data stored in 'table' - which I really need, and not its previous (outdated) version
        } else {
          console.log('Some error happened...');
        };
      });
}, 1000);
```